# How can I make sure my unposted answer was saved?

Tags: support

I wrote this long answer and couldn't finish it in one sitting (attention span issues) so I figured I could just close the site and pick up the saved draft where I left off some time later. That works for me most of the time. I hardly have this issue at all, but when I do I find that just the last 1 or 2 sentences I wrote weren't saved, not a problem; it allows me to rethink if I could word it better. This time, as I was writing an answer, I lost 2 paragraphs being unsaved.

I know there's some sort of text that pops up and says "draft saved", but I miss it *most* of the time(it's so tiny and it disappears fast). **Is there something I can do to check if the post was saved?** Or maybe there's a way to manually save on-site, or do I have to save it in a notepad before closing the site?

Comment: You might rather ask this on [meta.se]. There's nothing RPG-specific in here, and you're going to find broader expertise on the SE system's workings there.

Comment: huh, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146362/350545 thanks for directing me to the proper SE @doppelgreener